# Problem compiling simple C++ progam

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I was provided this simple C++ [I think] program to investigate the maximum size of int that can be stored:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <iostream>

void main ( int argc , char * argv[])

{

  cout << "INT_MAX      " << INT_MAX   << endl ;
  cout << "INT_MAX +1 = " << INT_MAX + 1  << endl ;
  cout << "INT_MAX -1 = " << INT_MAX - 1 << endl ;

  cout << "INT_MAX / INT_MAX        " << INT_MAX /INT_MAX << endl ;
  cout << "(INT_MAX +1) / INT_MAX   " << (INT_MAX +1) /INT_MAX << endl;
  cout << "(INT_MAX -1) / INT_MAX   " << (INT_MAX -1) /INT_MAX  <<endl;
  cout << "INT_MAX / (INT_MAX +1)   " << INT_MAX  /(INT_MAX+1)  <<endl;
  cout << "INT_MAX / (INT_MAX -1)   " << INT_MAX  /(INT_MAX -1)  <<endl;

}
```

I'm attempting to compile with:

```
gcc -o int_max int_max.cpp
```

But I get the following error:

```
int_max.cpp:4: error: '::main' must return 'int'
int_max.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
int_max.cpp:8: error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope
int_max.cpp:8: error: 'endl' was not declared in this scope
int_max.cpp:9: warning: integer overflow in expression
int_max.cpp:13: warning: integer overflow in expression
int_max.cpp:15: warning: integer overflow in expression
```

I tried adding a return 0 at the end of main but that didn't help.  Any idea what I've done wrong?

P.S It's possible this is actually a C snippet but I seem to remember the lecturer saying it was C++.

Cheers

Comment: change void main(...) to int main(...)

Comment: Also if its C++ take a look at the numeric_limits class from the limits header i.e #include <limit> rather than #include <limit.h>. It lets you write things like std::numeric_limits<int>::max() rather than INT_MAX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are compiling C++ code with `gcc` in a file with `.c` extension?

```
// Use new C++ header files instead of their .h version.
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>

// cout and endl are declared in the std namespace.
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char * argv[])    
{
  cout << "INT_MAX      " << INT_MAX   << endl ;
  cout << "INT_MAX +1 = " << INT_MAX + 1  << endl ;
  cout << "INT_MAX -1 = " << INT_MAX - 1 << endl ;

  cout << "INT_MAX / INT_MAX        " << INT_MAX /INT_MAX << endl ;
  cout << "(INT_MAX +1) / INT_MAX   " << (INT_MAX +1) /INT_MAX << endl;
  cout << "(INT_MAX -1) / INT_MAX   " << (INT_MAX -1) /INT_MAX  <<endl;
  cout << "INT_MAX / (INT_MAX +1)   " << INT_MAX  /(INT_MAX+1)  <<endl;
  cout << "INT_MAX / (INT_MAX -1)   " << INT_MAX  /(INT_MAX -1)  <<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

and use `g++` to compile.

Comment: Sorry no, I had tried it as both .c and .cpp, copy/pasted the wrong example.

I was also under the impression that gcc compiled c++ too?

Comment: @Adam: I've always encountered problems compiling C++ code with `gcc`, even when the file extension is `.cpp`. It fails linking C++ libs.

Comment: @Adam: `gcc` actually *does* compile C++ files if they have `.cpp` extension but it doesn't link to C++ standard libraries. I've successfully compiled a `.cpp` file (without linking) and linked the `.o` file with `g++`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem that I tend to refer to as *error message blindness*.  Consider your first error:

```
int_max.cpp:4: error: '::main' must return 'int'
```

The error here is that main() must return int.  You currently have main() declared as returning void.

For this error message:

```
int_max.cpp:8: error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope
int_max.cpp:8: error: 'endl' was not declared in this scope
```

All standard library functions and objects are contained within the `std` namespace.  That is, you can either:

```
std::cout << "whatever" << std::endl;
```

or:

```
using namespace std;

...

cout << "whatever" << endl;
```

Finally:

```
int_max.cpp:9: warning: integer overflow in expression
int_max.cpp:13: warning: integer overflow in expression
int_max.cpp:15: warning: integer overflow in expression
```

You have deliberately overflowed integers in these expressions.  If you take the maximum number an integer can hold and add one to it, what happens?  The compiler is warning you that you've done that.

Comment: Yes I'm deliberately overflowing to see *exactly* what happens.  And yes it is error message blindness as I never code in C++.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
void main ( int argc , char * argv[])
```

to

```
int main ( int argc , char * argv[])
```

add a using statement after the includes:

```
using namespace std;
```

and at the end of main function:

```
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

Comment: Return statement is optional in `main()`, complaint is due to the `void main()` declaration

Comment: No need to explicitly return anything. Check: http://zamanbakshifirst.blogspot.com/2006/11/c-c-main-should-return-void.html

Comment: @Manuel: No need to syntactically, but semantically, not returning anything says "I don't know what state my application was in when it stopped running", whereas `return 0;` says "My application ran successfully." What message do you want to send to your maintenance programmers?

Comment: @Bill: fall-through in main means "success".  I would expect my maintenance programmers to be well acquainted with that convention.

Comment: @Manuel: fall-through either means "success" or "I forgot to put something here"... how do you tell which just by looking at foreign code?

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```
void main ( int argc , char * argv[])
```

to

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
```

Comment: In fact it's not necessary to explicitly return 0. Check this: http://zamanbakshifirst.blogspot.com/2006/11/c-c-main-should-return-void.html

Comment: Updated answer based on comments.

Answer (score 0):

The first error is because the function main() is required by the C++ Standard to return an integer. Change to:

```
 int main ( int argc , char * argv[])
```

The remainder are because the objects named are in the `std` namespace. Add a using directive afuer your #includes:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

The warnings are becaiuse when you say something like:

```
INT_MAX + 1
```

you are trying to create  a value that is bigger than the biggest possible integer. This may or may not do what you want.

Comment: Yes I explicitly want to see the output.

Answer (score 0):

As Mehrdad has pointed out you are compiling compiling c++ code from a file with a .c extension.

Also you will need a "using namespace std;" in after your #include  if you aren't going to explicitly specify it for cout.